# Passing Q_GADGET as signal parameter from C++ to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qgadget

Can't get a property of a C++ object inside a QML code.
Object is passed as a parameter to the signal.

Expected that in QML, the property `text` of the `Record` object can be extracted. And the value should be `abc`. QML sees the object as `QVariant(Record)`, and its property `text` as `undefined`.

`Record` is a value-type like `QPoint`, so it uses `Q_GADGET` declaration.

hpp:

```
#ifndef LISTENP_HPP_
#define LISTENP_HPP_

#include <QObject>

#include "Record.hpp"

class ListenP: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    ListenP();
    virtual ~ListenP();

    void emitGotRecord();

signals:
    void gotRecord(Record r);
};

#endif /* LISTENP_HPP_ */
```

cpp:

```
#include "ListenP.hpp"

ListenP::ListenP() :
        QObject()
{
}

ListenP::~ListenP()
{
}

void ListenP::emitGotRecord()
{
    emit gotRecord(Record("abc"));
}
```

hpp for Record:

```
#ifndef RECORD_HPP_
#define RECORD_HPP_

#include <QObject>
#include <QMetaType>

class Record
{
Q_GADGET

Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText)

public:
    Record(const QString& text = "");
    ~Record();

    QString text() const
    {
        return m_text;
    }

    void setText(const QString& text)
    {
        m_text = text;
    }

private:
    QString m_text;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Record)

#endif /* RECORD_HPP_ */
```

cpp for Record:

```
#include "Record.hpp"

Record::Record(const QString& text) :
        m_text(text)
{
}

Record::~Record()
{
}

namespace
{
const int RecordMetaTypeId = qMetaTypeId<Record>();
}
```

QML piece:

```
Connections {
    target: listenPModel
    onGotRecord: {
        console.log(r)
        console.log(r.text)
    }
}
```

main piece:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

auto listenP = std::make_shared<ListenP>();
QQuickView view;
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("listenPModel", &*listenP);
view.setSource(QStringLiteral("src/qml/main.qml"));
view.show();

QtConcurrent::run([=]
{
    QThread::sleep(3);
    listenP->emitGotRecord();
});

return app.exec();
```

Log shows:

```
qml: QVariant(Record)
qml: undefined
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [release notes](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.5) for Qt 5.5 says for the new features:

> - Qt Core
>
>   - You can **now have Q_PROPERTY and Q_INVOKABLE within a Q_GADGET**, and there is a way to query the QMetaObject of such gadget using the QMetaType system

Indeed, compiling and running your example with Qt 5.4 gives the same result as yours *whereas* with Qt 5.5 I got `Record` correctly recognised, i.e. I got as a result:

```
qml: Record(abc)
qml: abc
```

Also, as stated in the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE), the type passed to the macro - `Record` in this case, should provide (1) a public default constructor, (2) a public copy constructor and (3) a public destructor. Since `Record` is a very simple class, there's no need to provide a copy constructor as the default one is sufficient.

Comment: Q_GADGET does not allow signals.

To get sample code to build, must use MEMBER keyword:
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text MEMBER m_text)

Comment: @pixelgrease it's a signal which uses the gadget as argument. It's not a signal withing qgadget. The answer and question code works perfectly fine.