# Accessing properties of a C++ object passed as signal parameter to QML

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qml

My goal is to pass an instance of the custom C++ class “Contact”  as a parameter “contact” of a signal “contactFound” emitted from the C++ class “ContactHelper” to QML; and in QML in the “onContactFound” signal handler to access the properties of the signal parameter “contact”.

From the QML side, the object “contact” is basically a data structure, with 2 read-only properties, and no methods.

I have tried 2 approaches, both shown in the example code at the bottom of this question. **EDIT:** In the original version of this question, neither worked. Thanks to comments from @BaCaRoZzo, approach 1 now works (and thus solves my immediate problem).

**Approach 1)** “Contact”  is modelled on the Custom Type examples “Block” and “Message” in the [QT documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-queuedcustomtype-example.html). i.e. “Contact” is declared  via **qRegisterMetaType**, and is NOT based on **QObject**, but uses the **Q_GADGET** macro (following input from BaCaRoZzo).

This approach works both when contact is passed to the signal by reference (&contact), and by value (contact), but fails when passed by by pointer / address (*contact).

**Approach 2)** “Contact2” based on a **QObject**, declared via **qmlRegisterType**, and passed  by pointer / address (*contact2).

The code compiles and runs, but neither approach gave me the expected signal parameter property access.

**Approach 1)** in QML the parameter “contact” of “onContactFound” is valid, but the properties of contact are undefined. **EDIT:** this is fixed by adding the missing **Q_GADGET** macro to contact.h

**Approach 2)** in QML the parameter “contact” of “onContactFound2” is not defined!

**EDIT:** Given that Approach 1 now works, I can use it in my real code, and slightly change the focus of this question, namely:

a) What is stopping Approach 2 (Object / qmlRegisterType / passed by pointer *) from working?

b) Assuming both approaches can be got working, which is the most suitable for transferring a light-weight read-only data-structure (a handful of string properties + 1 string array property) via signal parameter from C++ to QML?

I am developing with Qt5.5.1, with an Android 6.0.1 device as the target.

The example code below can be pasted into a new “QtQuick Controls Application” project.

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>
#include "contactshelper.h"
#include "contact.h"
#include "contact2.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<ContactsHelper>("ContactsHelper",1,0,"ContactsHelper");
    qRegisterMetaType<Contact>();
    qmlRegisterType<Contact2>("ContactsHelper",1,0,"Contact");
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

contact.h

```
#ifndef CONTACT_H
#define CONTACT_H
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMetaType>
class Contact {
    Q_GADGET //!!!This macro was missing in the original question!!!
public:
    Contact();
    Contact(const Contact &other);
    ~Contact();
    Q_PROPERTY(QString contactId MEMBER m_contactId)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString displayLabel MEMBER m_displayLabel)
    void setContactId(const QString contactId);
    void setDisplayLabel(const QString displayLabel);
private:
    QString m_contactId;
    QString m_displayLabel;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Contact)
#endif // CONTACT_H
```

contact.cpp

```
#include "contact.h"
#include <QDebug>
Contact::Contact(){}
Contact::~Contact(){}
Contact::Contact(const Contact &other) {
    qDebug() << "Contact: copy constructor called: " << other.m_displayLabel;
    m_contactId = other.m_contactId;
    m_displayLabel = other.m_displayLabel;
}
void Contact::setContactId(const QString contactId) {
    m_contactId = contactId;
}
void Contact::setDisplayLabel(const QString displayLabel) {
    m_displayLabel = displayLabel;
}
```

contact2.h

```
#ifndef CONTACT2_H
#define CONTACT2_H
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
class Contact2: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Contact2(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Contact2();
    Q_PROPERTY(QString contactId MEMBER m_contactId)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString displayLabel MEMBER m_displayLabel)
    void setContactId(const QString contactId);
    void setDisplayLabel(const QString displayLabel);
private:
    QString m_contactId;
    QString m_displayLabel;
};
#endif // CONTACT2_H
```

contact2.cpp

```
#include "contact2.h"
Contact2::Contact2(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}
Contact2::~Contact2() {}
void Contact2::setContactId(const QString contactId) {
    m_contactId = contactId;
}
void Contact2::setDisplayLabel(const QString displayLabel) {
    m_displayLabel = displayLabel;
}
```

contactshelper.h

```
#ifndef CONTACTSHELPER_H
#define CONTACTSHELPER_H
#include "contact.h"
#include "contact2.h"
#include <QObject>
class ContactsHelper : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ContactsHelper(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE void fakeContactFound();
    Q_INVOKABLE void fakeContactFound2();
signals:
    void contactFound(const int index, const int count, const Contact &contact);
    void contactFound2(const int index, const int count, const Contact *contact);
};
#endif // CONTACTSHELPER_H
```

contactshelper.cpp

```
#include "contactshelper.h"
#include "contact.h"
ContactsHelper::ContactsHelper(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}
void ContactsHelper::fakeContactFound() {
    qDebug() << "ContactsHelper: faking contactFound";
    Contact contact;
    contact.setContactId("123");
    contact.setDisplayLabel("Aunt Agatha");
    contactFound(1, 1, contact);
}
void ContactsHelper::fakeContactFound2() {
    qDebug() << "ContactsHelper: faking contactFound";
    Contact2 *contact  = new Contact2;
    contact->setContactId("123");
    contact->setDisplayLabel("Uncle Fred");
    this->contactFound2(1, 1, contact);
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import ContactsHelper 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    ContactsHelper {
        id: contactsHelper
        onContactFound: {
            console.log ("QML: onContactFound signal received!");
            console.log ("QML: displayLabel: " + contact.displayLabel);
            listProperty(contact);
        }
        onContactFound2: {
            console.log ("QML: onContactFound2 signal received!");
            console.log ("QML: displayLabel: " + contact.displayLabel);
            listProperty(contact);
        }
        function listProperty(item) {
            console.log ("QML: listing contact properties ...");
            for (var p in item)
                console.log(p + ": " + item[p]);
        }
    }
    MainForm {
        anchors.fill: parent
        button1.onClicked: {contactsHelper.fakeContactFound()}
        button2.onClicked: {contactsHelper.fakeContactFound2()}
    }
}
```

MainForm.ui.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
Item {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property alias button1: button1
    property alias button2: button2
    RowLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Button {
            id: button1
            text: qsTr("Fake contactFound")
        }
        Button {
            id: button2
            text: qsTr("Fake contactFound2")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433260/passing-q-gadget-as-signal-parameter-from-c-to-qml) works fine, expect that it uses `Q_GADGET` in place of `Q_OBJECT`, which seems fine for your case.

Comment: HI BaCaRoZzo. I saw that, and your answer too it. Am now re-reading.

Comment: As far as I can make out, his "Record" is equivalent to my approach 1 **Contact**, except that a) he uses the` Q_GADGET` macro, and b) in his **ListenP** (equivalent to my **ContactsHelper**) the **gotRecord** Signal takes the **Record** parameter _by value_ (as opposed to my attempts by _reference_ / _pointer_)

Comment: Approach 3 (Q_GADGET macro + object _pass by value_ to Signal parameter) works! 1000Grazie! I am still intrigued to find out what is wrong with approaches 1 and 2. I will update the question tomorrow morning with the new 3rd approach (must go to bed now). Also the test function listProperty() that I picked up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293838/qml-list-all-object-members-properties-in-console) does not work ...

Comment: I'm glad you solved. Well actually it should work also with the `Q_OBJECT`. It's quite strange it does not. The `Q_GADGET` was an addition of Qt 5.5 to use value types in QML without the overhead of the full QObject-related stuff. It's not mandatory. Can't speak for your code in detail since I just skimmed it when I've post my first comment.

Comment: ciao @BaCaRoZzo. I guess I have made a silly mistake with Q_OBJECT, that stops it working, and we will groan when we spot it. But given that in my use-case I am passing a read-only data structure to QML, Q_GADGET is  a better fit anyway. [My current, work-in-progress code is here](https://github.com/FlyingSheepOnSailfish/Landed4Android). Getting a Q_GADGET as a child of a Q_GADGET working was also tough, I had to workout how to override C++ operators. Ironically, I found it easier to pass data from Android / Java to C++, then to pass the same data further within Qt from C++ to QML!

Comment: Well, yeah, passing data between Java and C++ can be considered easier. It all boils down to have a nice, well explained example. :)