# Is there a way to define custom basic type in QML?

Tags: qml, qt5

I need it for returning my custom point type with specialized methods by value, not pointer, from C++ `Q_INVOKABLE` method to QML. I cannot return pointer because new points are created many times during calculations and its must be destroyed just after using.

Comment: Since Qt 5.5 you can use `Q_GADGET` to define value types. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31433260/2538363) and, most importantly, the link in the answer.

Comment: I got a message "Unknown method return type" from QML when returning my `Q_GADGET` object.

Comment: Do I need calling `qmlRegisterType` or `qmlRegisterUncreatableType` for my type?

Comment: Did you `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`-ed it as in the documentation? The code from the question works out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I did. It was just another error in my code. Now all works fine. Thanks!